# JavaFX: Paint program with Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, javafx-8, fxml

I need to create a JavaFX 8 Paint program using the Canvas scene, but the problem is when I try to create a square or a circle while I'm dragging the mouse in the Canvas, I erase the last figure with `gcs[fig].clearRect(startX, startY, bufferX, bufferY);` using a buffer but this erase the figure that is bellow. I don't want that, It has to be like windows Paint. Maybe a layer can help me but I don't know how to do it.

I use an Array of GraphicsContext to draw figures in every position of the array.

I'm using NetBeans IDE

JavaFX FXML Application

**MicroPaint.java**

```
package micropaint;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MicroPaint extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="micropaint.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <ToolBar orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="107.0">
        <items>
          <Button fx:id="rectButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setRectangleAsCurrentShape" text="Rectangulo" />
            <Button fx:id="lineButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setLineAsCurrentShape" text="Linea" />
            <Button fx:id="ovlButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setOvalAsCurrentShape" text="Ovalo" />
            <Button fx:id="pencButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setFreeDesign" text="Lapiz" />
            <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="78.0" text="Borrador">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="eraser" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setErase" text="Borrador" />
                <MenuItem fx:id="clean" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearCanvas" text="Limpiar" />
              </items>
            </MenuButton>
            <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="78.0" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="strokeRB" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Stroke">
               <toggleGroup>
                  <ToggleGroup fx:id="shapes" />
               </toggleGroup>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="fillRB" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fill" toggleGroup="$shapes" />
            <Slider fx:id="sliderSize" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="38.0" />          
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <Canvas fx:id="TheCanvas" height="453.0" layoutX="107.0" onMouseDragged="#onMouseDraggedListener" onMouseExited="#onMouseExitedListener" onMousePressed="#onMousePressedListener" onMouseReleased="#onMouseReleaseListener" width="512.0" />          
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
    package micropaint;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private GraphicsContext[] gcs;
    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private int fig=0;
    private boolean drawline = false,drawoval = false,drawrectangle = false,erase = false,freedesign = true;
    double startX, startY, lastX,lastY, bufferX,bufferY;
    double hg;

    @FXML private RadioButton strokeRB,fillRB;
    @FXML private Slider sliderSize;
    @FXML private ColorPicker colorPick;
    @FXML private Canvas TheCanvas;
    @FXML private Button rectButton,lineButton,ovlButton,pencButton;
    @FXML private MenuItem eraser;



    @FXML 
    private void clearCanvas(ActionEvent e){
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, 515, 453);
    }

    //private int bufferFig=0;

    @FXML
    private void onMousePressedListener(MouseEvent e){

        sliderSize.setMin(0);
        sliderSize.setMax(300);
        this.hg = sliderSize.getValue();

        gcs[fig]=TheCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        this.startX = e.getX();
        this.startY = e.getY();
        System.err.println("mousePressed at" + startX + ", "+ startY);
        /*if(drawoval)  
            this.dibujaOValo();
        if(drawrectangle)
            this.dibujaRect();*/
        bufferX = startX;
        bufferY = startY;
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseReleaseListener(MouseEvent e){
        //this.lastX = e.getX();
        //this.lastY = e.getY();
        //if(drawline)
        //    this.dibujarLinea();
        fig++;

        System.err.println(fig);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseDraggedListener(MouseEvent e){
        this.lastX = e.getX() - startX;
        this.lastY = e.getY() - startY;

        if(drawoval)  
            this.dibujaOValo();
        if(drawrectangle)
            this.dibujaRect();
    }

    private void dibujaOValo(){
        gcs[fig].setFill(colorPick.getValue());
        gcs[fig].setStroke(colorPick.getValue());

        if(strokeRB.isSelected() == true){

            gcs[fig].strokeOval(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
        }else
            gcs[fig].fillOval(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
    }

    private void dibujaRect(){
        gcs[fig].setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
        gcs[fig].setFill(colorPick.getValue());

        if(strokeRB.isSelected() == true){
            gcs[fig].clearRect(startX, startY, bufferX, bufferY);
            gcs[fig].strokeRect(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
        }else{
            gcs[fig].clearRect(startX, startY, bufferX, bufferY);
            gcs[fig].fillRect(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
        }
        System.err.println(fig);
        bufferX = lastX;
        bufferY = lastY;
    }

    private void dibujarLinea(){
        gcs[fig].setFill(colorPick.getValue());
        gcs[fig].setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
        gcs[fig].setLineWidth(5);
        gcs[fig].strokeLine(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
    }

   @FXML
    private void onMouseExitedListener(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println("No puedes dibujar fuera del canvas");
    }

    @FXML
    private void setOvalAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e){
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = true;
        drawrectangle = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase = false;

    }

     @FXML
    private void setLineAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e){
        drawline = true;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase = false;
    }
     @FXML
    private void setRectangleAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e){
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase=false;
        drawrectangle = true;
    }

    @FXML
    private void setErase(ActionEvent e){
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;    
        erase = true;
        freedesign= false;
    }

    @FXML
    private void setFreeDesign(ActionEvent e){
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;    
        erase = false;
        freedesign = true;
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        gcs = new GraphicsContext[100];
        gc = TheCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

        //////////////////////////////////
        Image imageRect = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Stop-32.png"));
        ImageView icR = new ImageView(imageRect);
        icR.setFitWidth(32);
        icR.setFitHeight(32);
        rectButton.setGraphic(icR);  

        Image imageLinea = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Ruler-32.png"));
        ImageView icLin = new ImageView(imageLinea);
        icLin.setFitWidth(32);
        icLin.setFitHeight(32);
        lineButton.setGraphic(icLin);

        Image imageOvalo = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Chart-32.png"));
        ImageView icOval = new ImageView(imageOvalo);
        icOval.setFitWidth(32);
        icOval.setFitHeight(32);
        ovlButton.setGraphic(icOval);

        Image imageLapiz = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Pencil-32.png"));
        ImageView icLapiz = new ImageView(imageLapiz);
        icLapiz.setFitWidth(32);
        icLapiz.setFitHeight(32);
        pencButton.setGraphic(icLapiz);
    }    

}
```

Comment: What is the array of `GraphicsContext` supposed to do? All elements of the array refer to the same object, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's supposed to be a layer! but doesn't work because as you say refer to the same object. I thought I can recover the figures that I created there somehow but don't know, some idea?

Comment: You almost have it with the layer idea. I am not up to date on javafx-8 so can not answer. At drag start create an image as a copy of the canvas and just draw the image to clear the canvas instead of clear. That in effect give you what you want. At the end of the drag, just draw the result and dump the image. BTW if you have that image you can use it as an undo if you keep it

Comment: To create layers with the canvas API you have to use multiple canvases. The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm#JFXGR214) has an example. But maybe it would be better not to use canvas at all and just to put shapes onto a pane?

Comment: @Blindman67 I will try what you say! I was doing exactly the same but without dumping the image.

Comment: @James_D I know dude, but my teacher wants me to do it with Canvas and FXML :c

Comment: @Blindman67 I made it :D ty for all

Comment: @James_D ty dude! ty for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Paint with JavaFX 8 - JavaFXML Canvas**

Here what I did

***MicroPaint.java***

```
package micropaint;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MicroPaint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

***FXMLDocument.fxml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="652.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="micropaint.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <ToolBar orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="107.0">
        <items>
          <Button fx:id="rectButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setRectangleAsCurrentShape" text="Rectangulo" />
            <Button fx:id="lineButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setLineAsCurrentShape" text="Linea" />
            <Button fx:id="ovlButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setOvalAsCurrentShape" text="Ovalo" />
            <Button fx:id="pencButton" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setFreeDesign" text="Lapiz" />
            <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="78.0" text="Borrador">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="eraser" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setErase" text="Borrador" />
                <MenuItem fx:id="clean" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearCanvas" text="Limpiar" />
              </items>
            </MenuButton>
            <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="78.0" />
            <RadioButton fx:id="strokeRB" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Stroke">
               <toggleGroup>
                  <ToggleGroup fx:id="shapes" />
               </toggleGroup>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="fillRB" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fill" toggleGroup="$shapes" />
            <Slider fx:id="sizeSlider" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="59.0" />          
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
      <Canvas fx:id="TheCanvas" height="453.0" layoutX="107.0" width="546.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="canvasGo" height="453.0" layoutX="107.0" onMouseDragged="#onMouseDraggedListener" onMouseExited="#onMouseExitedListener" onMousePressed="#onMousePressedListener" onMouseReleased="#onMouseReleaseListener" width="546.0" />          
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

***FXMLDocumentController.java***

```
package micropaint;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author CarlosA.
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Other variables<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    private GraphicsContext gcB,gcF;
    private boolean drawline = false,drawoval = false,drawrectangle = false,erase = false,freedesign = true;
    double startX, startY, lastX,lastY,oldX,oldY;
    double hg;
    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>FXML Variables<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    @FXML private RadioButton strokeRB,fillRB;
    @FXML private ColorPicker colorPick;
    @FXML private Canvas TheCanvas,canvasGo;
    @FXML private Button rectButton,lineButton,ovlButton,pencButton;
    @FXML private Slider sizeSlider;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @FXML
    private void onMousePressedListener(MouseEvent e){
        this.startX = e.getX();
        this.startY = e.getY();
        this.oldX = e.getX();
        this.oldY = e.getY();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseDraggedListener(MouseEvent e){
        this.lastX = e.getX();
        this.lastY = e.getY();

        if(drawrectangle)
            drawRectEffect();
        if(drawoval)
            drawOvalEffect();
        if(drawline)
            drawLineEffect();
        if(freedesign)
            freeDrawing();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseReleaseListener(MouseEvent e){
        if(drawrectangle)
            drawRect();
        if(drawoval)
            drawOval();
        if(drawline)
            drawLine();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onMouseExitedListener(MouseEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("No puedes dibujar fuera del canvas");
    }

    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Draw methods<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    private void drawOval()
    {
        double wh = lastX - startX;
        double hg = lastY - startY;
        gcB.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());

        if(fillRB.isSelected()){
            gcB.setFill(colorPick.getValue());
            gcB.fillOval(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }else{
            gcB.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
            gcB.strokeOval(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }
    }

    private void drawRect()
    {
        double wh = lastX - startX;
        double hg = lastY - startY;
        gcB.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());

        if(fillRB.isSelected()){
            gcB.setFill(colorPick.getValue());
            gcB.fillRect(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }else{
            gcB.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
            gcB.strokeRect(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }
    }

    private void drawLine()
    {
        gcB.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());
        gcB.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
        gcB.strokeLine(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
    }

    private void freeDrawing()
    {
        gcB.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());
        gcB.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
        gcB.strokeLine(oldX, oldY, lastX, lastY);
        oldX = lastX;
        oldY = lastY;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Draw effects methods<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    private void drawOvalEffect()
    {
        double wh = lastX - startX;
        double hg = lastY - startY;
        gcF.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());

        if(fillRB.isSelected()){
            gcF.clearRect(0, 0, canvasGo.getWidth(), canvasGo.getHeight());
            gcF.setFill(colorPick.getValue());
            gcF.fillOval(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }else{
            gcF.clearRect(0, 0, canvasGo.getWidth(), canvasGo.getHeight());
            gcF.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
            gcF.strokeOval(startX, startY, wh, hg );
        }
       }

    private void drawRectEffect()
    {
        double wh = lastX - startX;
        double hg = lastY - startY;
        gcF.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());

        if(fillRB.isSelected()){
            gcF.clearRect(0, 0, canvasGo.getWidth(), canvasGo.getHeight());
            gcF.setFill(colorPick.getValue());
            gcF.fillRect(startX, startY, wh, hg);
        }else{
            gcF.clearRect(0, 0, canvasGo.getWidth(), canvasGo.getHeight());
            gcF.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
            gcF.strokeRect(startX, startY, wh, hg );
        }
    }

    private void drawLineEffect()
    {
        gcF.setLineWidth(sizeSlider.getValue());
        gcF.setStroke(colorPick.getValue());
        gcF.clearRect(0, 0, canvasGo.getWidth() , canvasGo.getHeight());
        gcF.strokeLine(startX, startY, lastX, lastY);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @FXML 
    private void clearCanvas(ActionEvent e)
    {
        gcB.clearRect(0, 0, TheCanvas.getWidth(), TheCanvas.getHeight());
        gcF.clearRect(0, 0, TheCanvas.getWidth(), TheCanvas.getHeight());
    }


    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Buttons control<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    @FXML
    private void setOvalAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e)
    {
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = true;
        drawrectangle = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase = false;
    }

     @FXML
    private void setLineAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e)
    {
        drawline = true;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase = false;
    }
     @FXML
    private void setRectangleAsCurrentShape(ActionEvent e)
    {
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        freedesign = false;
        erase=false;
        drawrectangle = true;
    }

    @FXML
    private void setErase(ActionEvent e)
    {
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;    
        erase = true;
        freedesign= false;
    }

    @FXML
    private void setFreeDesign(ActionEvent e)
    {
        drawline = false;
        drawoval = false;
        drawrectangle = false;    
        erase = false;
        freedesign = true;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        gcB = TheCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gcF = canvasGo.getGraphicsContext2D();

        sizeSlider.setMin(1);
        sizeSlider.setMax(50);

        //////////////////////////////////
        Image imageRect = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Stop-32.png"));
        ImageView icR = new ImageView(imageRect);
        icR.setFitWidth(32);
        icR.setFitHeight(32);
        rectButton.setGraphic(icR);  

        Image imageLinea = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Ruler-32.png"));
        ImageView icLin = new ImageView(imageLinea);
        icLin.setFitWidth(32);
        icLin.setFitHeight(32);
        lineButton.setGraphic(icLin);

        Image imageOvalo = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Chart-32.png"));
        ImageView icOval = new ImageView(imageOvalo);
        icOval.setFitWidth(32);
        icOval.setFitHeight(32);
        ovlButton.setGraphic(icOval);

        Image imageLapiz = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Pencil-32.png"));
        ImageView icLapiz = new ImageView(imageLapiz);
        icLapiz.setFitWidth(32);
        icLapiz.setFitHeight(32);
        pencButton.setGraphic(icLapiz);
    }    

}
```

I use two Canvas in the FXML document, so I use one for the effects and other for the final figure.
The eraser doesn't work yet, you can improve it